# Detecting collision with arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, collision-detection, collision, maze

So I have a 2d map array printed out. I have 0's set as a space and 1 set as a wall. I have variables such as traps and health as well as the player. However, I am having trouble implementing a score as the two collide. I was wondering how I can detect when a player and life collide which would increment the health variable by 1. Right now it increments every time I move.
Thank you!
These are my variable functions

```
void putplayer()
{
    setcolor(9);
    gotoxy( player.x +mazex,    player.y  +mazey); 
    cout<<playersymbol;
    setcolor(7);

}

void puttreasure()
{
    setcolor(14);
    gotoxy(treasure.x +mazex, treasure.y +mazey);
    cout<<treasuresymbol;
    setcolor(7);

}

void puttraps()
{
    setcolor(14);
    gotoxy( traps.x +mazex,    traps.y  +mazey); 
    cout<<trapssymbol;
    setcolor(7);

}

void putlives()
{
    setcolor(14);
    gotoxy( lives.x +mazex,    lives.y  +mazey); 
    cout<<livessymbol;
    setcolor(7);

}

void moveleft()
{
    gotoxy(31,7);
    cout<<"left key   move player left    \n\n";
     if (maze[player.y][player.x-1]==0)   player.x = player.x -1;
}
```

Then my Main, however some code I took out as it might not be relevant

```
int main()
{
    DWORD        mode;          /* Preserved console mode */
    INPUT_RECORD event;         /* Input event */
    BOOL         EXITGAME = FALSE;  /* Program termination flag */
  //  unsigned int counter = 0;   /* The number of times 'Esc' is pressed */


    /* Get the console input handle */
    HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

    /* Preserve the original console mode */
    GetConsoleMode( hstdin, &mode );

    /* Set to no line-buffering, no echo, no special-key-processing */
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, 0 );

   srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed

    // Variables
    int health = 0;

   // Declare variable positions
    player.x=1;
    player.y=1;
    treasure.x = 1;
    treasure.y = 3;
    traps.x =  1;
    traps.y = 7;
    lives.x = 1;
    lives.y = 9;

    clrscr();
    setcolor(15);


    while (!EXITGAME)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject( hstdin, 0 ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)  /* if kbhit */
        {
            DWORD count;  /* ignored */

            /* Get the input event */
            ReadConsoleInput( hstdin, &event, 1, &count );

            /* Only respond to key release events */
            if ((event.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
            &&  !event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)

            clrscr();
            putmenu();
            gotoxy(6,20);
            cout<<"Lives: " << health;
            Sleep(100);


                switch (event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                {
                    case VK_ESCAPE:
                       EXITGAME = TRUE;
                     break;

                    case VK_LEFT:
                        // left key   move player left
                         moveleft();
                     break;

                    case VK_RIGHT:
                        // right key   move player right
                        moveright();

                     break;    

                    case VK_UP:
                        // up key   move player up
                        moveup();

                     break;

                    case VK_DOWN:
                        // down key   move player down
                         movedown();

                     break; 

                    case VK_A:
                        // left key   move player left
                        moveleft();

                     break; 

                    case VK_D:
                        // right key   move player right

                        moveright();
                     break; 

                    case VK_W:
                        // up key   move player up

                        moveup();
                     break; 

                    case VK_S:
                        // down key   move player down
                        movedown();
                     break; 


                }//switch

                putplayer();
                puttreasure();
                puttraps();
                putlives();




        }
                if(maze[player.x][player.y] = maze[lives.x][lives.y]){
                health++;
                }

                else if(maze[player.x][player.y] = maze[traps.x][traps.y]){
                health--;
                }
    }

    gotoxy(1,23);cout<<"  ";  
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, mode );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The move code looks like it'd be pretty relevant

Comment: I tried setting the arrays of the player and health equal to eachother and if so the health would go up. But it goes up every movement I make.

Answer (score 1):

You have the code

```
if(maze[player.x][player.y] = maze[lives.x][lives.y])
```

which sets the maze[player.x][player.y] to the value at maze[lives.x][lives.y], and then evaluates it (it will evaluate to true if 1 (wall), false if 0 (space)). I think you meant to have something like

```
if((player.x == lives.x) && (player.y == lives.y))
```

which will (as far as I can tell) evaluate if the player and the lives are at the same location.

Comment: Wow.... I can't believe that fixed it. So I have to evaluate each x and y position separately or else it will just set the player values to the y values? And thank you!

Comment: Well, if you mess up and use "=" you'll ASSIGN the left hand value to the right hand side. If you use "==" it'll EVALUATE if the left hand value and the right hand value are equal and return the corresponding boolean. It's a subtle difference since we use "=" for both of them in almost all other cases, but in coding the two are very different. Compilers don't complain because it's still valid :)

Also you need to compare the locations of players and lives, whereas you were actually checking if both the player and lives were on the same tile type (space or wall).

Glad to help.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that:
 if(maze[player.x][player.y]